# Building a site like skyscanner, kayak, google flights

Tags: api, aggregate

I use Skyscanner a lot myself, and one thing I don't like is the fact that I get redirected when I want to book. I want to know what the obstacles are in having a solution where you can book your flights without being redirected and without necessarily being a reseller/travel agent.

**The objective is to make comparison shopping seamless.**

I understand low-budget carriers prefer booking only on their site, but perhaps their strategy can be integrated within the comparison site.

I also understand that carriers would want customer analytics, but this can be made fully available to them.

What are the reasons for example KLM, Airfrance etc might NOT want to make comparison shopping seamless?

Answer (score 0):

I have been a main developer for one of such website which uses such APIs. I would list many reasons but also it is a good practice not to do so.

Just some reasons off the top of my head.

1) It is not the purpose of such websites. They just join an affiliate program to redirect users and get some small fees for purchases. They would keep their system as simple as possible.

2) Airline and other provider like hotels have their own policy on fees, refund, purchase, loyalty points etc. As a third party, you can not implement such a thing for each provider. If you dont implement, then you would use API, right? They wouldn't expose such inner workings of their system to third parties, payment involves PCI compliance, customer confidentiality etc.

3) Such services involve certain confidentiality and privacy. Somebody's passport, staying at a particular hotel or flying on a particular plane is sensitive information and should not be available to third parties.
Just imagine how many third parties their API are available. No trusted company would allow this to happen.

4) Even if they allow, no third party can really ensure security of such sensitive information. If a breach of security happens, thousands of airline data etc. would be affected.

5) Each of airline and hotels might be subject to different jurisdictions in terms of data protection etc. It is technically impossible to combine them.

many many other reasons..... There are also many issues in handling payment, accounting etc.